# What can i do to get few output files by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

My Webpack compiling all my project in one index.js. What can I do to get javascript code in "index.js" and css code in "style/index.css"?
My webpack.config.js:

`
    var path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'testApp/www/index.js'
  },  
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname,` "app"),
        query:
        {
          presets:['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

`

Comment: You need to use the extract text webpack plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/webpack-1/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ExtractTextPlugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

On console run `npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin`

In your webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'testApp/www/index.js'
  },  
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
        query:
        {
          presets:['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
     new ExtractTextPlugin('style/index.css')
  ],
};
```